# Why Is Arial Black Rendering in Italics?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

Been working on a site and the designer has decided to use Arial Black as the h1 & h2 font-face.

All is well however upon using this font I have quickly discovered it renders in Italics.

Has anyone else come across this issue? and if so what was your solution to rectifying this?
I'm not sure I can justify purchasing 'Arial Black' as its a windows standard font...

I read that there was an issue back in XP SP3 that the Arial Black font was overwritten with the Italics version.. but does this still persist in Windows7?

Just looking for someone to shed some light on the matter and in a perfect world, inform me of a solution.

Comment: check this page out to see if yours is rendering the same

http://web.mit.edu/jmorzins/www/fonts.html

Comment: What browser are you using?  It is not italics in Firefox.

Comment: The font must be wrong on your computer.

Comment: I have the same issue, it displays fine in Firefox, but in chrome Arial Black is displaying in Italics.

Comment: this fonts test page shows the issue in chrome as well http://www.triplesmart.com/fonts.html ... The issue shows up even if not using h1,h2 ...

Comment: Seems it was my own system fonts issue, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the issue for me, I had an Arial Black Italic font in my Windows Fonts that was causing that issue, removing it solved the issue.

1. Start -> Run : Type "%windir%\fonts" -> hit Enter
2. Find the "Arial Black Italic" font, move it to a temporary location (say My Documents)
3. Restart Chrome

You should be all good now ... [there are people out there who have had luck by removing all the Helvitica fonts](http://www.sevenforums.com/browsers-mail/56885-browsers-display-italic-text.html), not sure how that would help.

Answer (score 0):

Mine's not rendering any on that page in italic, you should should be able to target it with

`h1, h2 {font-style:normal;}`

Answer (score -1):

just add

```
font-weight: bold;
```

and it will be ok.

Answer (score -1):

just set css to:

```
font-weight: 900;
```