# itextsharp's Arial ,courier new font always show italic in windows 8

Tags: itext

why in windows 8 , I run below code,  which set font is Arial ,and font style is regular,

after PDF has been created.  [Why Is Arial Black Rendering in Italics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333898/why-is-arial-black-rendering-in-italics)
the font style become italic.   courier new font got the same issue.  only this two font has issue.

this code work fine in windows 7,  font style is regular.

```
string path = @"c:\test\";
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle r = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(400, 300);
Document doc = new Document(r);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(path + "Blocks.pdf", FileMode.CreateNew));
doc.Open();


BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\ariali.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, false);
//set font.style=0;
iTextSharp.text.Font newFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(baseFont, 16f, 0, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);
Chunk c1 = new Chunk("A chunk represents an isolated string. ", newFont);
doc.Add(c1);
doc.Close();
```

Comment: You use ariali.ttf which is Arial italic. Thus, it's no surprise you eventually get italics.

Answer (score 0):

try that its work for my.
and make sure that you use the right font

```
NormalFont ="C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\ARIAL.ttf";
BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontType, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(baseFont, fontSize, fontStyle);
Chunk chunk = new Chunk(str, font);
```